# Cutting off circulation

Tags: blood-circulation

How much force is required to cut off the blood circulation of, lets say the average human arm? I'm asking because i'm bored and want to try it on myself. I know that in just a couple of seconds with lack of blood flow you will lose complete use of your arm. I'm only going to do this for a second or two with people watching so please do not worry about safety!

Comment: If you are losing use of an arm within a couple of seconds that is because you are compressing a nerve and blocking transmission of motor signals, not because of cutting off blood circulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure you need to apply is equal to your systolic blood pressure, about 120 mmHg. This is about 163 g/cm^2.

Comment: Thank you for the information boreora I wish you good fortune

Comment: Can you add resources to these numbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_pressure